# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, pdf

See the following code:

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult GetPDF()
{
    byte[] pdf = GetPdfFromDatabase();
    return new FileContentResult(reportData, "application/pdf");
}
```

***View:***

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("GetPDF","Account")" width="600" height="500"></iframe>
```

***Javascript Console:***

[image]

> *Each time you load a page, show this warning !!!*

Comment: Is the file not downloading or are you just concerned about the message?

Comment: @KSib, concerned about the message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For who come across this topic. (Me too.) For best solution is you need to create HTML page to act as iframe landing page to show PDF content.

This is example html. I just extract from chrome.

```
<html><body style="background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38); height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px;"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="your_pdf_url" type="application/pdf"></body></html>
```

Just replace `your_pdf_url` to your real url. I just add this html as middleware in Laravel and show this HTML so Chrome will not warning anymore. You can use this html as base and create better pdf landing page such as custom loading.

Comment: Thank you brother, the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 18):

An iframe requests the resource mentioned in src attribute with a content type text/html. So this message only says "I requested html but server responded with pdf"

Comment: So no need to worry about this warning?

It's not a problem ?

Comment: Yes, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the warning can't be ignored.

An alternative I found to this problem, use the object tag, like this:

<object  data="your-data-base-64" type="application/pdf"></object>

and if you using angularJS, to prevent error on console do:

<object  ng-attr-data="your-data-base-64" type="application/pdf"></object>

Comment: Could you clarify why you think this warning can't/shouldn't be ignored?

Comment: Sorry, it's just my opinion, but if you use the tip i sent, the warning will not be displayed.